# Writing a dictionary to csv works with file from UbuntuVM but not from Windows

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nonetype

```
from sys import argv
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import csv

name, filename = argv

d = PyDictionary()

csv_columns = ['Word', 'Noun', 'Verb', 'Adjective', 'Adverb']
csv_file = 'trans_test.csv'
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w+') as f:
        with open(filename, 'r') as g:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = csv_columns)
            w.writeheader()
            for i in g:
                word = (i.split(' ')[0])
                dict1 = d.meaning(word)
                dict1['Word'] = word
                w.writerow(dict1)
except IOError:
    print('I/O error')
```

**I'm getting errors:**

```
Erorr: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "my_trans.py", line 19 in module<>
dict1['Word'] = word
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

**I'm trying** to extract first word from each line in txt file, get definitions of that word, put it in the dictionary, add this word with key 'Word' to that dictionary and write this to the csv file.

**What I tried and checked**:

-dict1 is NoneType, I don't know why - however when I put `dict1 = d.meaning(word)` outside try except, dict1 is a dictionary

**-I'm working on UbuntuVM, and when I'm creating file.txt with words on VM, script works, but when I brought file created in Notepad on Windows I'm getting this errors**

-if I write content of the file down on UbuntuVM, script works, but if I copy content of the file brought from Windows to file in Ubuntu it also doesn't work

-file from Windows Notepad is saved with utf-8

file.txt looks like this:

```
﻿renowned - (known or talked about by many people; famous)
prevalent - (widespread in a particular area at a particular time)
lesion - 
aneurysm - (an excessive localized enlargement of an artery caused by a weakening of the artery wall)
ischemic - 
juvenile - 
ashen - (of the pale gray color of ash)
inflammation - 
conned - 
intermittent - (occurring at irregular intervals; not continuous or steady)
mild -
```

Answer (score 0):

[PyDictionary.meaning](https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary/blob/79a791f853795baab11e9a91e404d83d29bfc889/PyDictionary/core.py#L116) scrapes http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu to get the definition.  It looks as if what's happening is that it's failing to retrieve the expected content, and this causes an error in `PyDictionary`:

> Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range

In this situation, `PyDictionary.meaning` returns `None`, causing the TypeError that you  are seeing.

This might be a temporary issue, or it could be that there is something about your Windows environment that causes the error.